# How to share interface declarations across multiple projects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

We use interfaces in our Typescript project for defining custom business objects passed around our application.

These are meaningless to the outside world, but we have many projects where sharing these interface definitions would be of benefit.

I was wondering if we could define these business object interfaces in some form of @types file so that other Typescript projects can pull these in.

The other approach I have considered is just to have a repo containing our interface files all hanging off a common  namespace so we can pull down this repo and copy over which ever interfaces we need into the project we are working on. Then it's just a case of namespace dot whatever to access them in our main ts files.

I'm trying to determine if there is an easy way to define these interfaces once and use everywhere rather than keep having to redeclare them from scratch in each project.

Has anyone out these done this kind of thing before? Are there any best practices we should look to follow?

Comment: It's just a code management issue. We use [gemfury](https://gemfury.com/) to create a private npm repo for similar reasons (our generic API and DTO definitions), but you could just as well have a git repo you include as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron how would including the git repo as a dependency work? Is there anything you can refer me to?

Comment: Check out the docs on [git urls as dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)